# Jsoup connection with basic access authentication

Tags: java, jsoup, basic-authentication

Is there a way in Jsoup to load a document from a website with basic access authentication?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With [HTTP basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) you need to send the `Authorization` header along with a value of `"Basic " + base64encode("username:password")`.

E.g.

```
String username = "foo";
String password = "bar";
String login = username + ":" + password;
String base64login = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(login.getBytes());

Document document = Jsoup
    .connect("http://example.com")
    .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
    .get();

// ...
```

*(explicit specification of character encoding in `getBytes()` is omitted for brevity as login name and pass is often plain `US-ASCII` anyway; besides, Base64 always generates `US-ASCII` bytes)*

Answer (score 7):

```
//Log in
Response res = Jsoup
    .connect("url")
    .data("loginField", "login")
    .data("passwordField", "password")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();

Document doc = res.parse();


//Keep logged in
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

Document doc2 = Jsoup
    .connect("url")
    .cookies(cookies)
    .get();
```

Comment: The OP asked about http basic authentication. This solution is for form-based auth which is something else entirely.

Comment: It's a useful answer in general.  Maybe editing the question to ask about auth in general would lead to a better post?

Comment: @YuriSchimke 1) Editing the question after it has been answered turns existing answers into nonsense because they refer to a different question. 2) The question that corresponds to this answer has been asked plenty of times already, and has better answers than this. 3) I found this question because I searched for specific terms that matched the question I had. If this question were changed, it would no longer match the question I had, and I wouldn't have found this question or BalusC's correct answer. Changing a properly-answered question is never a good idea.