# How to login via jsoup incase of pop-up?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am working on a application where I need to login via popup in jsoup.

[Here's the page](https://www.nebraska.gov/sos/corp/corpsearch.cgi).
After opening look for **If you are a Nebraska.gov subscriber, please log in.**

I don't know what to provide as post request in jsoup.

Here's what I have done so far.

```
String url = "https://www.nebraska.gov/sos/ccorp/";
Connection.Response response = Jsoup
    .connect(url)
    .timeout(30000)
    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
    .userAgent(
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0")
    .execute();

    Document document = response.parse(); // search results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

You can send this kind of request in this way:

```
package com.github.davidepastore.stackoverflow33967883;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

/**
 * Stackoverflow 33967883 question.
 *
 */
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String username = "foo";
        String password = "bar";
        String login = username + ":" + password;
        String base64login = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes()));
        String url = "https://www.nebraska.gov/sos/ccorp/";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .timeout(30000)
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .userAgent(
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
                .execute();

        Document document = response.parse(); // search results
    }
}
```

My dependencies in my `pom.xml` file (`commons-codec` for `Base64` class):

```
<dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679916/jsoup-connection-with-basic-access-authentication).

Comment: Thanks for the answer