# Get website content that that require google auntentication

Tags: java, android, httpclient, google-signin, apache-httpcomponents

I'm developing an app for school project, the site that I'm trying access is a site of my school where I can see my grades, this site requires an autentication with an a google account they gave us, is there a way to download the content with HTTPClient or something similar in Java?

Comment: After you have the access token, you can use an HTML parser to get the content from the pages (maybe you need to perform some operations for the authentication but that depends on how the authentication is implemented in your school). I suggest you to us [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) to get the HTML content. Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679916/jsoup-connection-with-basic-access-authentication you can find a basic example with token